# How to restore python3 installations to default on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04. I had deleted `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/lib/python3/` because some packages were giving errors with the binary file. I meant to reinstall `python3` to a fresh state, but I didn't know deleting those files would wreck my system.
None of the `apt` commands are working. They give an error saying `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`. This is what I get on using `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-8 g++-9 libaccinj64-11.2 libcub-dev libcublas11 libcublaslt11 libcudart11.0
  libcufft10 libcufftw10 libcuinj64-11.2 libcupti-dev libcupti-doc libcupti11.2
  libcurand10 libcusolver11 libcusolvermg11 libcusparse11 libllvm11:i386 libluajit-5.1-2
  libluajit-5.1-common libnppc11 libnppial11 libnppicc11 libnppidei11 libnppif11
  libnppig11 libnppim11 libnppist11 libnppisu11 libnppitc11 libnpps11 libnvblas11
  libnvjpeg11 libnvrtc11.2 libnvtoolsext1 libnvvm4 libobs0 libthrust-dev libvdpau-dev
  node-html5shiv nsight-compute nsight-compute-target nsight-systems
  nsight-systems-target nvidia-cuda-gdb nvidia-cuda-toolkit-doc nvidia-opencl-dev
  nvidia-profiler nvidia-visual-profiler obs-plugins ocl-icd-opencl-dev opencl-c-headers
  opencl-clhpp-headers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tlpui (0.1.20210103-1~focal0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tlpui.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package tlpui (--configure):
 installed tlpui package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 12
7
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tlpui
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives

```
Setting up tlpui (0.1.20210103-1~focal0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/tlpui.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package tlpui (--configure):
 installed tlpui package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tlpui
```

How do I restore everything to the original state without reinstalling the OS? I have `python3.9` in `/usr/lib/`. Can I configure everything to use this python, and get everything working?

P.S. I forgot to mention that `python3` works when I type it in the terminal. To be more precise, I get this when I use `python3`

```
Python 3.8.7 (default, Jun 21 2021, 14:17:23) 
[GCC 10.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: You better ask this question on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

You said you deleted `/usr/bin/python3` and `/usr/lib/python3/` for some package issues, and this is definitely not encouraged unless you really know what you are doing. A better way to handle the Python packages is to use virtual environments: both Anaconda and pyenv are good options.

It is not hard to install pyenv following the ReadMe in their Github repo: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

The system needs its own Python to do its tasks. Unless you are learning about the system itself on some virtual machines, don't delete anything manually in system folders. If you are using a virtual machine, you can just reinstall the system to fix this issue.

If you don't want to reinstall the system, the simplest way is to use VMWare, Virtual Box, or Parallels Desktops to install a virtual machine that has the same version of Ubuntu and copy the files you deleted back into your system.